# Insert data into intermediary table while submitting main modelform in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a Task model. I want to assign task to multiple users so i have taken `ManytoMany` relationship. So Django is creating a `ManytoMany` table but i want to track that which user has completed task and when. So I took intermediary model by using **`through='TaskComplete'.`** Now I can not see task_assign_to feild in form. And even i declare in `modelForms` and submit it gives below error.

```
Cannot set values on a `ManyToManyField` which specifies an intermediary model. Use audit.TaskComplete's Manager instead.
```

Now I want that admin selects the user from main form and into intermediary model.

I tried but can not find any solution for this. below is my code. Please guide me how to do it?

**My Model:**

```
class Task(models.Model):

    task_audit_title    = models.ForeignKey(MainAudit,on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='audit_title_for_task',verbose_name= ('Audit Title'))
    task_subtask_name   = models.ManyToManyField(SubTask, related_name='subtask_for_task',verbose_name= ('Subtask Title'))
    task_subject        = models.CharField(verbose_name= ('Task Subject'),max_length=100,blank=False)
    task_description    = models.CharField(verbose_name= ('Task Description'),max_length=1000,blank=True)
    task_assign_to      = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='task_assign_to', through='TaskComplete')
    task_assign_by      = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='task_crt_by')
    task_deadline       = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    task_perticulars    = models.ManyToManyField(Perticular, related_name='task_perticular', blank=True)
    task_created_time   = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    task_modified_by    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='task_mod_by', null=True, blank=True)
    task_modified_time  = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    is_del              = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("change_temp_delete_task", "Can delete temporarily"),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_subject

    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('create-task')


class TaskComplete(models.Model):
    task_title          = models.ForeignKey(Task,on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='assigned_task')
    is_completed        = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    task_cmt_by_doer    = models.CharField(verbose_name= ('Submit Comment'),max_length=100,blank=True)
    completed_by        = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name = 'task_completed_by')
    completed_time      = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**My View:-**

```
class TaskCraeteView(LoginRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
    # permission_required = 'Company.add_company'
    model=Task
    success_message = " Task Craeted successfully!"
    reverse_lazy('create-task')
    login_url = 'login'
    template_name = 'create-task'
    form_class = TaskCreateForm
    # fields =[]


    def form_valid(self,form):

        form.instance.task_assign_by = self.request.user
```

My traceback [my traceback link](http://dpaste.com/1NKD3SQ)

**My Form**

```
class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['task_audit_title','task_subtask_name','task_subject','task_description',
              'task_assign_to','task_deadline','task_perticulars']
```

Comment: Your exception suggests an error not related to the models you have shared. Is there an audit model? Can you share the traceback?

Comment: no audit is my app name

Comment: A membership model?

Comment: Please share the traceback

Comment: Extremely sorry, you were right. I pasted the wrong error. I have updated the exception.

Comment: Can you share the traceback? It's hard to see where the error is occurring

Comment: updated traceback link. sorry for delay and thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in your TaskCreateForm can you share that?

Comment: Yes, Updated form.